# Error:cannot find symbol -variable

Tags: java, string

I'm having problems with this simple code when creating an object of it. I'm using BlueJ.

```
    public class Car 
    {
       private String brandName; 
       public Car(String brand) 
       {
       this.brandName = brand;
       }


       /**
       * @return the brand name of the car
       */
       public String getBrandName() 
       {
       return brandName;
       }

    }
```

Comment: yeah. Can you give us a line number of the error?

Comment: it doesn't show any line number. It compiles. I get this error when I try to create the object. It looks like this : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45630219/Untitled.png

Comment: from your screenshot it looks like the ferrari instance of Car isn't setup correctly.. maybe there are other error messages somewhere in a log file or console output?

Comment: I only have this code. I wrote the ferrari string after I opened the create object window .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclosing "Ferrari" in double quotes to make it a literal string.  Otherwise it looks like it's trying to find the variable named Ferarri.